# Meta-analysis of Odds Ratios and Asymmetric Confidence Intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, meta-analysis, odds-ratio

I've come across a series of association studies that report odds and asymmetric confidence intervals. The standard meta-analytic techniques I've used assume symmetrical confidence intervals to calculate the standard error. I'm not sure if there are standard practices for this and here my naive thoughts:

1. Use the smaller CI and calculate the SE from it. This would assume it was calculated using a consistency standard error and that the other CI was calculated using an agreement standard error.
2. Calculate the log(OR) and its SE assuming that both boundaries were calculated using a consistency standard error (which we know it's true).
3. Use some other approach (haven't found any in the literature) and/or software functions.

Data looks like this:

> 1.03   1.00    1.06
> 1.012  1.011   1.014
> 1.35   1.16    1.59
> 1.89   1.1 3.26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 2 is the standard way to go especially since you will be doing your meta-analysis on the scale of log odds. You may end up presenting it as OR of course but the underlying analysis would be on the log scale.